# Callout post method : submit value failed!

Tags: callout

Have checked the codes many times, looks all ok...

However, the remote side responds there's no value transmitted.

What's the wrong?

```
String mob = 'MOB';
String msg = 'MSG';

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_form_method_post.asp';
String bodyStr = 'fname='+mob+'&lname='+msg;

req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(bodyStr);
req.setCompressed(true);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
String retStr = res.getBody();
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method_post
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_form_method_post.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the following line, it works.

```
req.setCompressed(true);
```

This method is documented as...

> If true, the data in the body is delivered to the endpoint in the gzip compressed format. If false, no compression format is used

My guess would be that the **demo_form_method_post.asp** does not support compression.

Comment: You are exactly right.